# Checking if there is a mobile modem on Dell Precision M4500 with Fedora 17

Tags: fedora, modem, mobile

I am using a Dell Precision M4500. I've realized that there is a SIM slot underneath the battery slot, I suppose it is for using mobile broadband access.

I am usually connecting to the Internet through the tethered signal from my Android mobile and I was thinking that it may be easier to configure the PC to use the SIM from my phone and get Internet access directly.

The first thing I need to confirm is that there is actually a broadband modem or some device that can connect to 3G and not just the slot in the computer bones.

I've tried `lspci` and `lsusb` but I cannot recognize any device that could be a 3G modem.

Here the output

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev    02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 82801 SATA RAID Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT216 [Quadro FX 880M] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
04:00.0 CardBus bridge: Ricoh Co Ltd Device e476 (rev 02)
04:00.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 03)
04:00.4 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd FireWire Host Controller (rev 03)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ca:1814 Ricoh Co., Ltd HD Webcam
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:8187 Dell Computer Corp. DW375 Bluetooth Module
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor`
```

Can someone help me understand if what I want to do is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dell has versions of their laptops with and without the chipset for 3G. The slot is available whether the chip is installed or not. Looks like you don't have the 3G hardware though. You can check by opening up the laptop. The wwan/3g chip usually has a place next to the bluetooth and wifi chip and is removable.